# Renewing a gravel driveway

Tags: driveway

I'm doing a project that includes removing the top 2-3" of pea gravel and dirt .The customer wants # 8's for top layer. I think I should put down a 3" layer of # 53's. My question is should I put dry cement on top of 53's and lightly wet it then compact it or do I not need to use cement?

Comment: don't use any cement, that will mess up draining and prevent support matrixing.

Comment: I have used Portland cement on crushed rock and shale but probably would not with pea gravel, pea gravel never locks together well even with cement, a 3/4 minus packed then a dusting of Portland cement really helps to prevent wash out my neighbor an my last place had added rock 3 times and asked how I never had to it was because of the cement swept into the rock locked ever together, I did put more where I expected run off after using a grass seed spreader then I swept it around so it lodged in the cracks works great, I did add a bag to the most tire worn area several years later it helps